# i can't navigate to router-outlet inside another

Tags: angular, router

I have 2 router-outlet in my project and one inside on the other the first one is the default app router-outlet and the second one is inside one of the 'home' component in which I want to show other components when I click on the toolbarso  this was the solution that I found to navigate  to the second one 
**html file :**

```
   <mat-toolbar >
      <a routerLink="/sessionag">Session</a>


      <button mat-button style="background-color: #80D0D0" (click)="logout()">logout</button>

    </mat-toolbar>
    <mat-drawer-container >
      <mat-drawer-content style="color: #333333 ;background-color: white">
        <router-outlet name="second"></router-outlet>

      </mat-drawer-content>
    </mat-drawer-container>
```

**AppRoutingModule file :**

```
 const routes: Routes = [

  {path:'sessionag',
    component:SessionAgComponent,outlet:'second'},

];
```

but this is not working for me i don't know why .
did i do something wrang or it does not work like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so what I was looking for actually is a router outlet inside another and the answer that I found is to add the component  as  children of the component in which I want to add the second router-outlet like this :
**in app-routing-module**

```
    const routes: Routes = [
      {path:'home',
    component:HomepageComponent,
    children:[
      {path:'sessionag',
        component:SessionAgComponent},
      {path:'sessiontek',
        component:SessionTekComponent},
    ]
  },
];
```

**in the .ts file**

```
this.router.navigate(['/home/sessionag']);
```

**in HTML file**

```
 <router-outlet ></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're not navigating to the primary router, you have to tell angular what `router-outlet` you want to route to.

Using the `routerLink` directive you can specify the outlet you want to route to:

```html
<a 
  [routerLink]="[{ outlets: {second: ['sessionag'] } }]">
  Session
</a>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-route-starter-gcdouz) on Stackblitz

Comment: added a demo on stackblitz .. are there any errors on your console